# xframe_options_exempt for a Django TemplateView

Tags: django, iframe

I am trying to add the decorator @xframe_options_exempt into a django template view but it complais with a

> Exception Value:   'dict' object has no attribute
>   'xframe_options_exempt'

I noticed in Django 1.9 docs the decorator is used for views with a request parameter and I am using a TemplateView.

Is it possible to use it like this?

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    """
    """

    template_name = 'app/template.html'

    from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt

    @xframe_options_exempt
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = {}
        context['test'] = 'hello'

        return context
```

Basically I need to embed a django template view into an iframe

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you are [decorating class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views), you should use `method_decorator`. You should override a method that takes the `request` as an argument, e.g. `dispatch` (will apply to all request types) or `get` (will apply to get requests but not post requests). As you found, decorating `get_context_data` will not work.

```
class MyView(TemplateView):

    @method_decorator(xframe_options_exempt):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that by using `super()` you don't have to duplicate the code from `TemplateView`.

You can decorate the class if you prefer (Django 1.9+)

```
@method_decorator(xframe_options_exempt, name='dispatch')
class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'
```

Comment: Nice, I knew there is a cleaner way to do it

Comment: So I tried both versions above, but none of them worked for me. It sill says "Refused to display * in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." Any idea why?

Comment: It would be better to ask a new question rather than commenting here. I'm not familiar with the clickjacking protection features, so I can't help.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the available `@xframe_options_exempt` decorator, you can also implement a mixin class to be mixed into your view classes:

```
class XFrameOptionsExemptMixin:
    @xframe_options_exempt
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class SomeView(XFrameOptionsExemptMixin, TemplateView):
    …
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if anyone else has this problem, this decorator cannot be applied to get_context_data method, but you can override the get method from the TemplateView, something like this:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    """
    """

    template_name = 'app/template.html'

    from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt

    @xframe_options_exempt
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = {}
        context['test'] = 'hello'

    return context
```

And this will do the trick